# postgres view update underlying table schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with a table `t` and a view `v` referencing `t`. Here `v` is selecting `t.*`.
When I now add a field to `t`, `v` is not updated, the field does not appear in the view. I also realized that when I dump the schema, the view is not saved with `t.*`, but with `t.col1,t.col2...`.
Is there a nice way to re the view else than just rerunning the definition?

Also if I dropped a column in `t`, wouldn't this cause an error in `v`?

By the way my postgres version is 11.14.0

Comment: You might be able to get the view automatically updated using triggers. Yes, if you drop a column in a table then it will break any view that references that column

Comment: I would think that re-creating the view is conceptually the correct way of treating a DDL change.